# How get the 10 most viewed pages (not post)

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes, pages

I would like to know how it's possible to get the 10 most viewed pages ?
I know how make it with post, but not with page...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: just add the code you use in page template. Pages are posts.

Comment: This doesn't work : `<?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=10&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC');
                     while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>`    That is my code and it just get me the post (article); Thanks for your fast answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query pages you have to choose `post_type=page` - of course.

Another "problem" is that the commen count isn't exactly representing post/page views. If you really want page views - not comment count - try something like the function below - I got that from here: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/.

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

With that you would have to query for the new meta key `post_views_count`. That's all - good luck!

Comment: Just remember that counting views in this way ins't very good idea if your site is popular. It will update your database every time someone visits any page of your site. It's a lot of update queries.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż: That's true, I probably should mentioned that. Do you have a more efficient way in mind? For actual page views. And if so, could you share it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't :( Well, you could use Google Analytics API to do it (I guess), but it definitely is more complex solution (and assumes you use GA).

Comment: Too bad, that would be interesting. I guess Google Analytics is a way to do it, but personally I only use it if really necessary, so, a internal solution is preferable - for me at least. To summarize if you are planing to use a solution working with post meta **make sure** *your server plan has the scale to do so without slowing your site down to much*.

Comment: Well, doing stats yourself on your server is generally a bad idea - it will always use a lot of resources...

Comment: Sure, it uses resources, but if you want total control you have to go with a selfhosted/internal solution. I'm absolutely not suggesting everyone should do so, but sometimes that is what is wanted. Because of that I wouldn't say it's generally a bad idea.

Comment: Of course there are many situations, when own/custom stats are best. But in most cases, I guess, GA (or other ready to use stats) should be enough (and I really don't think that you will implement more advanced stats than you get from these systems).